# Use copied file path in terminal (from applescript and automator)

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to create a simple workflow that will be used to help non-technical people use tesseract OCR. I have no problem using it myself, but others probably prefer GUIs, so I'm working on the following automator workflow (image below): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxiQVt7sQigQwgjpscG-0E9loCRO7Fxe/view?usp=sharing

Script:

```
set appName to "Terminal"

if application appName is running then
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "tesseract /Users/jackson/Downloads/OCRTemp.jpg /Users/jackson/Downloads/OCRTemp.txt"
    end tell

else
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "tesseract /Users/jackson/Downloads/OCRTemp.jpg /Users/jackson/Downloads/OCRTemp.txt" in front window
    end tell
end if
```

The problem is that in the line `"tesseract /Users/jackson/Downloads/OCRTemp.jpg /Users/jackson/Downloads/OCRTemp.txt"` I would like to replace the first file extension with the clipboard. Not being well versed in how to use bash, I'm not entirely sure what to do. I think part of the confusion is that I'm using an applescript to run a terminal command, so I'm not sure if I use applescript or terminal to get the variable.

[image: Automator workflow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for Automator.

Just use AppleScript (Change `/opt/local/bin/tesseract` to the output of `which tesseract`):

```
set myFile to (choose file with prompt "Choose a file to convert") # Get the file to convert
set myFilePOSIX to the POSIX path of myFile # Get terminal friendly path
set myLocation to (choose folder with prompt "Choose a location to save your file") # Get location to save the file
set myLocationPOSIX to the POSIX path of myLocation
tell application "Finder"
    display dialog "Choose a file name" default answer (name of file myFile as string) # Type the name the file
    set myName to the text returned of the result # Get what user typed
end tell
do shell script "/opt/local/bin/tesseract " & quoted form of myFilePOSIX & " " & quoted form of myLocationPOSIX & quoted form of myName # Do the terminal command
```

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you. I tried that and I'm not sure why, but I'm getting the error: `error "sh: /usr/local/bin/tesseract: No such file or directory" number 127`

Is this because of where I've stored tesseract?

Comment: @user279242 Yes. I can fix just run this command and post the output `which tesseract`

Comment: I assume you mean to terminal. Here's the output: `/opt/local/bin/tesseract`
thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @user279242 Fixed. Try now.

Comment: Thanks! One last question. When I try PDFs, it says `error "Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica
Error in pixReadMem: Pdf reading is not supported
Error during processing." number 1` Does this basically mean I can't OCR PDFs? I can always do images if I have to - Never mind found this: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1476 thank you for your help.